# HtmlTable Header Cell not Aligned when viewing in Outlook

Tags: c#, html, html-table, outlook

I am unable to get my first Header cell to be aligned no matter what I tried (when viewing in Outlook)

The last cell Header was originally misaligned too, and was one line above from the center. I managed to align the last Header cell.

May I know if there are workarounds on this, or if there are cleaner solution for my approach?

[image]

HTML Output

```html
<table border='1' width='100%'>
   <tr>
      <th style='vertical-align: top'>Others Subsidy Start Date</th>
      <th style='vertical-align: top'>Others Subsidy End Date</th>
      <th style='vertical-align: top'>Center</th>
      <th style='vertical-align: top'>Child Name</th>
      <th style='vertical-align: top'>Child BC</th>
      <th style='vertical-align: top'>Upcoming Disbursement Amount</th>
      <th style='vertical-align: top'>Disbursement Number</th>
      <th style='vertical-align: top'>Number of Remaining Disbursements</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style='vertical-align: top'></td>
      <td style='vertical-align: top'></td>
      <td style='vertical-align: top'>User Acceptance Testing Centre</td>
      <td style='vertical-align: top'>UAT Jackson Loh</td>
      <td style='vertical-align: top'>TXXXXXXXK</td>
      <td style='vertical-align: top'>$20</td>
      <td style='vertical-align: top'>2</td>
      <td style='vertical-align: top'>2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

---

C#

```
HtmlTableRow row;
row = new HtmlTableRow();

row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = "Others Subsidy Start Date" });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = "Others Subsidy End Date" });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = "Center" });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = "Child Name" });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = "Child BC" });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = "Upcoming Disbursement Amount" });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = "Disbursement Number" });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = "Number of Remaining Disbursements" });
table.Rows.Add(row);
row = new HtmlTableRow();

row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = othersSubsidyStart.ToString() });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = othersSubsidyEnd.ToString() });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = centre });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = childName });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = childBC });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = "$" + ((double)dAmount1).ToString() });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = "1" });
row.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell { InnerText = remainingDisbursements.ToString() });
table.Rows.Add(row);
row = new HtmlTableRow();

output = (mailMessage.ToString())
            .Replace("<table>", "<table border='1' width='100%'>")
            .Replace("<td>Others Subsidy Start Date</td>", "<th style='vertical-align: top'>Others Subsidy Start Date</th>")
            .Replace("<td>Others Subsidy End Date</td>", "<th style='vertical-align: top'>Others Subsidy End Date</th>")
            .Replace("<td>Center</td>", "<th style='vertical-align: top'>Center</th>")
            .Replace("<td>Child Name</td>", "<th style='vertical-align: top'>Child Name</th>")
            .Replace("<td>Child BC</td>", "<th style='vertical-align: top'>Child BC</th>")
            .Replace("<td>Upcoming Disbursement Amount</td>", "<th style='vertical-align: top'>Upcoming Disbursement Amount</th>")
            .Replace("<td>Disbursement Number</td>", "<th style='vertical-align: top'>Disbursement Number</th>")
            .Replace("<td>Number of Remaining Disbursements</td>", "<th style='vertical-align: top'>Number of Remaining Disbursements</th>")
            .Replace("<td>", "<td style='vertical-align: top'>")
            + "<td><b>Upcoming Disbursement Amount: $" + totalDisbursementAmount + "</b></td>";
}
```

---

Comment: Your C# code is not relevant at all. Please provide **only** the output (the html) so we can understand what is the issue there.

Comment: Noted @Dekel, I have added it in.

Comment: Please clean this (you shouldn't have the \r\n\t there - it's not really part of the string output).

Comment: It was the generated output before being parsed. Okay I'll clean it.

Comment: I changed your codeblock into a snippet. It seems to look ok, so I'm not sure if this is exactly your core.

Comment: Regardless- there is some `<td>` there after the table-closing. What is going on there?

Comment: Thanks. I ran in snippets, they turn out well, the issue surfaced when viewed in Outlook

Comment: That's an extra line I added in after the table, which displays a 'total' amount. I will remove it.

Comment: So you have a c# question (that is not related to c# at all), and the problem is with outlook (and you didn't mention outlook even once in your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For outlook?

Are you creating an HTML email?

Try rendering the following:

```html
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.myawesomehead{vertical-align:top;}
.myawesomecell{font-weight:bold;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table border="1" width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td class="myawesomehead,myawesomecell">Others Subsidy Start Date</td> 
      <td class="myawesomehead,myawesomecell">Others Subsidy End Date</td>
      <td class="myawesomehead,myawesomecell">Center</td>
      <td class="myawesomehead,myawesomecell">Child Name</td>
      <td class="myawesomehead,myawesomecell">Child BC</td>
      <td class="myawesomehead,myawesomecell">Upcoming Disbursement Amount</td>
      <td class="myawesomehead,myawesomecell">Disbursement Number</td>
      <td class="myawesomehead,myawesomecell">Number of Remaining Disbursements</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="myawesomecell"></td>
      <td class="myawesomecell"></td>
      <td class="myawesomecell">User Acceptance Testing Centre</td>
      <td class="myawesomecell">UAT Jackson Loh</td>
      <td class="myawesomecell">TXXXXXXXK</td>
      <td class="myawesomecell">$20</td>
      <td class="myawesomecell">2</td>
      <td class="myawesomecell">2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

In my experience adding CSS to the head tag and wrapping tag attributes in double(") instead of single(') saves few problems in various email clients.
In the code you'll have to deal with back slashes.

Comment: May I know how can I replace the single quotes with double quotes? I tried `string.Replace("'", "\"")` and it included the backslash inside the replacement too

Comment: Haha! Yes, this can be tricky.
Before now I've declared a constant variable:

const string myawesomequote = "\"";  

Then use it in your replace function call:

output = (mailMessage.ToString())
            .Replace("<td>", "<td class=" + myawesomequote + "myawesomecell" + myawesomequote + ">")

I hope this helps.